# Hibernate vs EclipseLink

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I'm starting a new Web project and I've chosen JPA as my persistence ORM engine.

Although I've used OpenJPA in my last project, now I want to use EclipseLink.

Why? It is the JPA reference implementation, it has a lot of documentation and a very good support in the Eclipse IDE. Also, I can't found any benchmark that declares none of them to be the best, so performance is not a factor (all implementations has its own strength points).

But, I want to use the JSR-303 validation spec, and I've chosen hibernate-validator (witch is the reference implementation of the Bean Validation spec).

Moreover, I'm using Spring, and there are a lot of examples with Spring+Hibernate, but I haven't found any opinion that said Spring is better with Hibernate.

Is there any problem mixing this two implementations?
Would be better to use Hibernate JPA with Hibernate Bean validation?

Comment: I never tried it in combination with Spring - but Hibernate Bean validation and EclipseLink are used in Glassfish.... so usability is proven. I also *prefer* EclipseLink to Hibernate because it automatically supports an extended open session for lazy loading.

Comment: All JPA 2 implementations (if compliant) will allow use of ANY Bean validation implementation. And if something is a "reference implementation" it means that was used as a way of proving that the JPA spec is implementable ... *nothing more*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate or EclipseLink for JPA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234829/hibernate-or-eclipselink-for-jpa)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been using `EclipseLink` implementation of JPA with Spring and `Hibernate-validation-4.2.0.Final`. And no problem so far. Now to answer your question:

> Is there any problem mixing this two implementations?

I don't think there will be any problem using `EclipseLink` JPA implementation with `Hibernate` implementation for JSR-303 validation spec together, as the purpose of these two specifications are different:

- JSR 303 - Bean Validation - defines a metadata model and API for entity validation. This is not tied to a specific application tier or programming model.
- JPA - This is the specification of the Java API for the management of persistence and object/relational mapping with Java EE and Java SE.

Spring provides full support for the JSR-303 Bean Validation API. You just need to have a JSR-303 provider, such as Hibernate Validator, present in the classpath and will be detected automatically.

And the Spring JPA, available under the `org.springframework.orm.jpa` package, offers comprehensive support for the `Java Persistence API` in a similar manner to the integration with `Hibernate`.